# can't get transparent background-color on this slider

Tags: css

I'm pulling my hair out on this and I've been going over the CSS for the last few hours.  I can not figure out how to get the background color on the slider at the top of this website to have the same transparent effect that I have on all the other parts of the page.  Any help from someone smarter than me would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the page:
http://rattletree.com/wordpress2/

I have put this CSS in just about every div that I can tell is associated with the slider and still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
.et_pb_fullwidth_code.et_pb_module{
background:transparent!important;
background: rgba(0,90,100,0.4)!important;
}

.recent-post-slider.design-4 .post-image-bg{
background:transparent!important;
background: rgba(0,90,100,0.4)!important;
}

.slick-slider{
background:transparent!important;
background-color: rgba(0,90,100,0.4)!important
}

.et_pb_section_0{
background:transparent!important;
background-color: rgba(0,90,100,0.4)!important
}
```

Comment: this property is applied currently `background: rgba(0,90,100,0.4)!important;`

Comment: The 0.4 is an Alpha which should be making it translucent like the other boxes-however it is not translucent, it is opaque.  I am trying to make the top slider translucent like the bottom widgets.

Comment: I am not sure if I am looking at the correct thing but it seems like you have an image which is occupying the entire size and it doesn't seem to be transparent or translucent. If you make that image transparent then the background-color on the container will have an effect (and show through the page background).

Comment: I am editing my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I check you code and find some answers to your problem.
1) You set the background color to several elements so it overlap and finish with full opacity. So first thing keep only one background-color

2) The background-image is not the background of all the article but only the content, So we need fix that too.

this code may fix your problem :

```
/* FIX BACKGROUNDS */
.et_pb_fullwidth_code.et_pb_module{
    background:transparent!important;
    background: rgba(0,90,100,0.4)!important;
}
/* FIX BACKGROUND_IMAGE */
.et_parallax_bg et_pb_parallax_css {
    background-image: none;
}
.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_parallax.et_pb_section_1.et_pb_with_background.et_section_regular {
    background-color: transparent;
}
article#post-37 {
    background-image: url(http://rattletree.com/wordpress2/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/91815-JoelLavioletteandRattletree-Rattletree-027.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachement: fixed;
}
```

Have a nice day, you should really use IDs in your html.